# Wordpress: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY) site broken

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

new here and a bit of a noob. was trying to add a field to a custom post type and ended up with a parse error message on all website pages. I've pasted the error message and the contractor-type.php code can anyone tell me how to fix this? I've had no luck reaching the hosting provider to do a full restore. Thanks very much for any and all suggestions. I don't have ftp access at the moment all ive been able to do is use the file manager in the hosting control panel to try to upload backed up copies of the theme files to no avail.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY), expecting ')' in /home/renovant/public_html/wp-content/themes/renovantage/self-developed-plugin/contractor-type.php on line 212

```
    <?php


function get_contractor_info($id)
{
    if($id==0)return;
    $p      = get_post($id);
    $infos  = get_post_custom($id);
    $return = array();
    $return['id']       = $id;
    $return['company']  = $p->post_title;
    foreach($infos as $key => $vls)
    {
        $return[$key] = $vls[0];
    }
    return $return;
}
add_action( 'init', 'tr_contractor_type' );


function tr_contractor_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Contractors', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Contractor', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New Contractor', 'article'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Contractor'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Contractor'),
        'new_item' => __('New Contractor'),
        'view_item' => __('View Contractor'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Contractor'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No Contractors found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Contractors found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
        );

    $supports = array(
        'title',
    //  'editor',
        //'author',
        'thumbnail',
        //'excerpt',
    //  'comments',
    //  'custom-fields',
    //  'trackbacks',
        'revisions'
        );


    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'supports' => $supports,

        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'contractor','with_front' => false ),
        'taxonomies' => array('category')
        );

    register_post_type('contractor', $args);
}


add_action('admin_init','tr_admin_init_add_con');
function tr_admin_init_add_con()
{
    global $wpdb;

    if($_GET['act'] !='cc')return;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT * FROM ".'wpms1_contractor'." ");

    foreach($results as $row)
    {
        $post_title = $row->company;
        $post_content = '';
        $post_status = 'publish';
        $post_type   = 'contractor';
        $postdata = compact('post_author', 'post_date', 'post_date_gmt', 'post_content', 'post_title', 'post_category', 'post_status', 'post_excerpt', 'comment_status', 'ping_status', 'to_ping', 'post_type', 'post_name', 'post_password', 'post_parent', 'menu_order', 'tags_input', 'page_template');
        //$post_id = wp_insert_post($postdata);
        //$post = $wpdb->get_row("select ID from {$wpdb->posts} where post_title = '{$row->company}'");

       if($post_id>0)
       {
            update_post_meta($post_id,'address',$row->company_address);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'address2',$row->company_address2);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'city',$row->company_city);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'province',$row->company_province);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'country',$row->company_country);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'postal_code',$row->company_postal);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'owner',$row->company_owner);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'contact_name',$row->company_contact);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'phone1',$row->company_phone);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'phone2',$row->company_phone2);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'fax',$row->company_fax);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'website',$row->company_website);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'email',$row->company_email);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'email2',$row->company_email2);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'overview',$row->company_overview);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'motto',$row->company_motto);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'services',$row->company_services);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'postal_prefixes',$row->postal_prefix);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'profile_column_1_title',$row->title1);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'profile_column_1_description',$row->description1);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'profile_column_2_title',$row->title2);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'profile_column_2_description',$row->description2);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'profile_column_3_title',$row->title3);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'profile_column_3_description',$row->description3);
       }
    }
}

//hide button media
add_action('admin_menu','tr_admin_menu_landing_hidemedia',11);
function tr_admin_menu_landing_hidemedia()
{
    $rs = wp_get_current_user();
    foreach((array) $rs->roles as $role)
    {
        if($role == 'subscriber')
        {
            remove_menu_page('upload.php');
        }
    }
}

function tr_landing_is_admin()
{
    $rs = wp_get_current_user();
    foreach((array) $rs->roles as $role)
    {
        if($role == 'administrator')
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


$profile_metaboxs =array();

$Company_fields = array(
                        'address' => 'Address',
                        'address2' => 'Address2',
                        'city' => 'City',
                        'province' => 'Province',
                        'country' => 'Country',
                        'postal_code' =>'Postal Code',
                        'website' => 'Website',
                        'owner' => 'Owner',
                        'contact_name' => ' Contact Name',
                        'phone1' => 'Phone 1',
                        'phone2' => 'Phone 2',
                        'fax' => 'Fax',
                        'email' => 'Email',
                        'email2' => 'Email2',

                        );
$Company_fieldsb= array();
foreach($Company_fields as $k => $f)
{

    $Company_fieldsb[] = array(
                        'id'=>$k,
                        'label'=>"{$f}:",
                        'name'=>$k,
                        'type'=>"text"
                    );
}

$profile_metaboxs[] = array(
        'id'=>'profile-meta-box-1',
        'title'=>'Company Information',
        'page'=> 'contractor',
        'context'=>'normal',
        'priority'=>'high',
        'fields'=>$Company_fieldsb
    );

$profile_metaboxs[] = array(
        'id'=>'profile-meta-box-2',
        'title'=>'Profile Overview',
        'page'=> 'contractor',
        'context'=>'normal',
        'priority'=>'high',
        'fields'=>array(
                     array(
                        'id'=>'overview',
                        'label'=>"Overview:",
                        'type'=>"textarea",
                        'height' => '100px'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>'motto',
                        'label'=>"Motto:",
                        'type'=>"textarea",
                        'height' => '100px'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>'services',
                        'label'=>"Services:",
                        'type'=>"textarea",
                        'height' => '100px'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>'postal_prefixes',
                        'label'=>"Postal Prefixes:",
                        'type'=>"textarea",
                        'height' => '100px',
                        'readonly' => (!tr_landing_is_admin())
                    ) 
        // LINE 212 as per comment from OP
    );

$profile_metaboxs[] = array(
        'id'=>'profile-meta-box-3',
        'title'=>'Profile Column 1',
        'page'=> 'contractor',
        'context'=>'normal',
        'priority'=>'high',
        'fields'=>array(
                     array(
                        'id'=>'profile_column_1_title',
                        'label'=>"Title:",
                        'type'=>"text",
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>'profile_column_1_image',
                        'label'=>"Image:",
                        'type'=>"img",
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>'profile_column_1_description',
                        'label'=>"Description:",
                        'type'=>"textarea",
                        'height' => '100px'
                    )
        )
    );


$profile_metaboxs[] = array(
        'id'=>'profile-meta-box-4',
        'title'=>'Profile Column 2',
        'page'=> 'contractor',
        'context'=>'normal',
        'priority'=>'high',
        'fields'=>array(
                     array(
                        'id'=>'profile_column_2_title',
                        'label'=>"Title:",
                        'type'=>"text",
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>'profile_column_2_image',
                        'label'=>"Image:",
                        'type'=>"img",
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>'profile_column_2_description',
                        'label'=>"Description:",
                        'type'=>"textarea",
                        'height' => '100px'
                    )
        )
    );

$profile_metaboxs[] = array(
        'id'=>'profile-meta-box-5',
        'title'=>'Profile Column 3',
        'page'=> 'contractor',
        'context'=>'normal',
        'priority'=>'high',
        'fields'=>array(
                     array(
                        'id'=>'profile_column_3_title',
                        'label'=>"Title:",
                        'type'=>"text",
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>'profile_column_3_image',
                        'label'=>"Image:",
                        'type'=>"img",
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>'profile_column_3_description',
                        'label'=>"Description:",
                        'type'=>"textarea",
                        'height' => '100px'
                    )
        )
    );
  $profile_metaboxs[]=array(
        'id'=>'page-meta-box-6',
        'title'=>'Header Box',
        'page'=> 'contractor',
        'context'=>'normal',
        'priority'=>'high',
        'fields'=>array(                
                    array(
                        'id'=>"header_title",
                        'label'=>"Title:",
                        'name'=>"header_title",
                        'type'=>"text"
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>"header_content",
                        'label'=>"Content:",
                        'name'=>"header_content",
                        'type'=>"text"
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>"header_link_text",
                        'label'=>"Text Link:",
                        'name'=>"header_link_text",
                        'type'=>"text"
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>"header_link_url",
                        'label'=>"Link:",
                        'name'=>"header_link_url",
                        'type'=>"text"
                    ),

            )
    );  
foreach ($profile_metaboxs as $meta_box) {
    $my_box = new Ant_Meta_Box($meta_box);
}

add_filter('post_row_actions', 'tr_landing_row_actions');
function tr_landing_row_actions($actions){
  global $post;

    if($post->post_type == 'contractor')
    {
        $actions['referral'] = '<a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/referral/'.$post->post_name.'" >Referral</a>';
    }

    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: as crazy as it sounds, we don't have a way to know which is the line 212 your error says.

Comment: thanks for giving it a look anyway

Comment: you're supposed to tell us which line is line 212!

Comment: my bad, obviously not very well versed in this stuff.

Comment: Just about the end, before `foreach ($profile_metaboxs as $meta_box) {` there is a line `                    ),` **notice the comma!**, that seems smelly... But then there is `'email2' => 'Email2',` that has a comma at the end too...

Comment: line 212 appears to be the line above the ); above the profile metabox. I tried to attach a snippet 
array(
         'id'=>'services',
         'label'=>"Services:",
         'type'=>"textarea",
                        'height' => '100px'
        ),
                    array(
         'id'=>'postal_prefixes',
         'label'=>"Postal Prefixes:",
         'type'=>"textarea",
                        'height' => '100px',
                        'readonly' => (!tr_landing_is_admin())
        )
        
    );
    
$profile_metaboxs[] = array(

Comment: There's an extra comma in `'email2' => 'Email2',` try removing it as in `'email2' => 'Email2'` (for one thing)

Comment: thanks very much for the responses will try implementing

Comment: @user2820037 `ppeterka 66's` answer makes sense. I missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a missing bracket...

```
    $profile_metaboxs[] = array(
    'id'=>'profile-meta-box-2',
    'title'=>'Profile Overview',
    'page'=> 'contractor',
    'context'=>'normal',
    'priority'=>'high',
    'fields'=>array(
                 array(
                    'id'=>'overview',
                    'label'=>"Overview:",
                    'type'=>"textarea",
                    'height' => '100px'
                ),
                array(
                    'id'=>'motto',
                    'label'=>"Motto:",
                    'type'=>"textarea",
                    'height' => '100px'
                ),
                array(
                    'id'=>'services',
                    'label'=>"Services:",
                    'type'=>"textarea",
                    'height' => '100px'
                ),
                array(
                    'id'=>'postal_prefixes',
                    'label'=>"Postal Prefixes:",
                    'type'=>"textarea",
                    'height' => '100px',
                    'readonly' => (!tr_landing_is_admin())
                )
      ) // <------------------------------ this "(" is missing from your code...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error will probably be caused by a statement that is not closed however we have noway to check what line 212 is. Here is an example:

```
211 echo "Hello"
212 $example = array("1","2")
```

Whereas this should be:

```
211 echo "Hello";
212 $example = array("1","2");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: the error has been fixed by the hosts thanks very much for the suggestions and input

Comment: Glad to here the issue is fixed :)